# How to reinsert corrected rows from the conflict table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, merge-replication

I have a bidirectional merge replication. I had failure constraints because the primary key was just integer. I change the primary key to the old primary key + a location identifier.The problem is how can I reinsert the old rows of conflict table ( that I can correct manually from MSmerge_conflict_) to the publishers and subscribers. 
can you help me please?

sorry for making faults, I'm not english speaker

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: yes now I have not primary key conflicts because I added a location identifier. I edited the MSmerge_conflict_ to correct the old rows but I have no idea to reinsert the corrected rows without doing it one by one (with command update or conflict viewer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Conflict Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189029.aspx) to submit the winning or losing row.

Comment: thanks brandon but assuming there is 1000 losing rows there is no stored procedure or command that can be used?

Comment: You may want to look at this:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2011/04/19/clearing-resolved-merge-replication-conflicts.aspx

Comment: There is a chance that it doesn't work for you since these are primary key conflicts.  You could however modify the script to delete one of the conflicting rows.

Comment: thanks but the script delete the loosing rows even if I corrected them. I want to reinsert them into the publisher.I am trying to that by using sql requests. is there a means to say to the merge agent that these lines are corrected and must be reinserted